# AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate methods aren't being called every time

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avcapturesession

I'm building a custom camera, and I'm having flakey results. When I attempt to capture an image, I'm *sometimes* not receiving the expected delegate callbacks. For example, here are my delegate methods:

```
func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willBeginCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    print("will begin")
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, willCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    print("will capture")
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didCapturePhotoFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings) {
    print("did capture")
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishCaptureFor resolvedSettings: AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, error: Error?) {
    print("finished capture")
}

func photoOutput(_ output: AVCapturePhotoOutput, didFinishProcessingPhoto photo: AVCapturePhoto, error: Error?) {
    print("finish process")
}
```

I have a button that triggers the following method:

```
func capture() {
    print("capture called")
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    captureOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)
}
```

Every time this method is called, I expect the following output in the console:

```
capture called

will begin
will capture
did capture
finish process
finished capture
image set
```

However, it seems like a 50/50 chance that I only get the following output:

```
capture called
did capture
```

What's going on here?

Comment: Hmm, strange. Have you tried using a separate class as a delegate and create a new instance for each capture request (like in Apple's AVCam example)? I could imagine that something is blocking the processing of your captured images for some reason...

Comment: Does anyone have a solution to this problem? I am also getting this exact behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing the same issue, but it was because I was calling `stopRunning()` on the capture session right after calling `capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)`

I ended up removing the `stopRunning()` call and it got fixed.

```
func takePicture() {
        let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()    

        imageOutput?.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

        videoPreviewLayer?.connection?.isEnabled = false // to freeze the image
}
```

However, take into account you need to call `stopRunning()` at some point (for example on `viewWillDisappear`)

I found this example from Apple that really helped me
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/cameras_and_media_capture/avcam_building_a_camera_app

Comment: this comment helped me...thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem. I could not get to the bottom of it, but I was able to get around it by switching the output from `AVCapturePhotoOutput` to `AVCaptureVideoDataOutput`. I found this article really helpful: https://medium.com/@barbulescualex/making-a-custom-camera-in-ios-ea44e3087563